# How can I connect to the local Rocksdb instance used by my parity node?

Tags: parity, database

I want to see everyones balances, and eventually try to create a realtime visualisation of the state. If I have a node with 10 GB of disk space used by the db, I understand this is Rocksdb taking up the space yeah? About 9,500 MB presently.

Possible to do? 
Default root password for the database then is.... ? What is a good client to connect with? Thanks in advance internets!

```
1864    ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/overlayrecent/db
1872    ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/overlayrecent
1206348 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/restoration/temp
4598188 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/restoration/db
5804540 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/restoration
3694172 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/current
9498716 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot
9500592 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d
9500596 ./.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db
```